# MYSQL Bulk insert failed to import the CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a CSV file with field delimiter as '**~:-**' and row delimiter as '**!^(**'. When I execute the Bulk insert query as follows

**QUERY FOR INSERTION**:

```
"BULK INSERT SAMPLETABLE FROM sample.csv WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '~:-',ROWTERMINATOR = '!^(',ERRORFILE = 'C:/log/error.log',KEEPIDENTITY, KEEPNULLS,FIRSTROW = 2, DATAFILETYPE='widechar')".
```

I get the **SQLException**: Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

I made sure the end of file is not '\n'. The other tables which are working, does not end with '\n'.

Even though **ERRORFILE** option is enabled in the SQL query, I am not seeing the error.log file getting created when SQLException is thrown.

Comment: Is this a one time thing?

Comment: No this is consistently happening

Comment: No, what I mean is, is this a standard process, whereby you are automating something, or are you doing a single bulk load?

Comment: this is an automation, not single bulk load

Comment: No, ROWTERMINATOR = '!^('. The csv file doesn't not end with '\N'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the root cause, I was doing a data migration from older version of the database to newer version. Found out that there is a **schema change** in the newer table, hence i got **SQLException**. Irony is that the Exception thrown didn't specifically indicate the Schema change.